# Which build should be shared with QA for testing? Signed release apk or Signed debug apk?

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, apk, release

I need my app to be tested thoroughly in all respects. For that purpose I need my app apk to be shared with QA team. Which build should I generate for testing purpose? Signed release apk or signed debug apk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signed Debug, will also give you the ability to ADB into the devices and access logs/act on crashes.

You might consider using something like [Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics) in addition to capture any stacktraces you might not have the ability to get yourself at the time of a crash.